# Setting background image of button in C#

Tags: c#, image, button, background

I want to set an image as background of a button of Windows Forms.

The image is added to the project´s resources.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You would use this when you load your application, or whenever you want to set it.

```
button.BackgroundImage = YourApplicationNamespace.Properties.Resources.yourImageHere;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the [BackgroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx) property of the Button. An example:

```
button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Image));
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered if it is.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, you can do this:

1. Go to the properties for your button and click the `BackgroundImage` item.
2. Click the '...' icon.
3. Click the radio button next to 'Local Resource'.
4. Click 'Import' and select the item you wish to have as the background.
5. Then, click 'Ok'.

Or, from code you can do this:

```
button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Image));
```